# PDF OBFUSCATION

Tags: pdf, obfuscation, ghostscript

Is there a safe way to prevent that text can be copied from a PDF document by editing the CMap table? So it still is readable, but when I copy some text and paste it in text editor, it shows as symbols and gibberish or wierd characters.
The protection with a password can be removed very quickly with appropriate software.

Comment: If it's on the screen then an image can be grabbed (even if only by a phone camera) and subjected to OCR to get the text. If you don't want the data to be copied, don't supply the data.

Comment: There are several solutions that turn text drawing instructions into vector graphic instructions, making regular text extraction impossible. Nonetheless, ocr will work (unless you make the quality of your pdfs extremely poor). So if you only are afraid of people copying&pasting, you can prevent that, but it will only replace your problem by people ocr'ing.

Comment: If you control access to the PDF then you could force users to view the PDF in your own viewer, where you could prevent copy+paste of text (but still allow searching for example). However, as mentioned above, you cannot prevent someone from screen grab and doing OCR on the pages.